# How do I use a radio button to send a user to a new website in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

What I want the program to do is make a form and have 2 radio buttons and 1 text.
Then I want it to collapse the text and radio value together into one and take me to that page:

If I input text with like "facebook" and the radiobutton value is .com I want it to take facebook + .com and send me to that page.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<title>A Basic Form</title>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>

<body onunload="Bye()">

<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Redirection: </legend>
        <div>
            <label>Where do you want to go?</label>
            <input type="text" id="input" name="input" size="7">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="go()">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" id="no" name="end" value=".no">
            <label for=".no">.no</label>
            <br />
            <input type="radio" id="com" name="end" value=".com">
            <label for=".com">.com</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function go() {
        var end = "";
        if (document.getElementById("no").checked) {
            end = document.getElementById("no").value;
        } else {
            end = document.getElementById("com").value;
        }

        var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
        var together = input + end;
        window.location.replace("http://www." + together);
    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It doesent redirect me

Comment: It works for me what browser are you using?

Comment: Probably not related, but `for` attribute should refer to `id`, not to `value`.

Comment: im using googlechrome

Comment: I Am on google chome as well. and the code snippet above works just fine for me.

Comment: I'm using chrome and when I enter espn in your demo it works.

Comment: but when im using the Notepad++ and run it in chrome it doesent work

Comment: did you save as html file?

Comment: yes i did save it html

Comment: Typing "facebook" into the input, selecting ".com" and clicking submit does not work for me. However, if I type something else (I used "bb") in the text box and hit submit, it works just fine.

Comment: snippet is working for me. What is saying you log console?

Comment: Look at my answer it will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, return false from the onclick handler to prevent the form submit.

Try this code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Redirection: </legend>
        <div>
            <label>Where do you want to go?</label>
            <input type="text" id="input" name="input" size="7">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return go()">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="radio" id="no" name="end" value=".no">
            <label for=".no">.no</label>
            <br />
            <input type="radio" id="com" name="end" value=".com">
            <label for=".com">.com</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function go() {
        var end = "";
        if (document.getElementById("no").checked) {
            end = document.getElementById("no").value;
        } else {
            end = document.getElementById("com").value;
        }

        var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
        var together = input + end;
        window.location.replace("http://www." + together);
        return false;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[brso05](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4028085/brso05)'s analysis seems to be spot on... But I can't really explain it. It seems that Chrome is delaying the side effects of the `location.href.replace` (which should be navigating away from the page) until after the form submit... I have a feeling you have hit a browser bug here. I can't imagine this is spec-compliant.

Answer (score 3):

Change type="submit" to type="button".

Change this line:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="go()">
```

to:

```
<input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="go()">
```

In this case you don't need to submit a form.  You are just trying to redirect the url.  You didn't specify where to submit the form so it is submitting to itself that is your problem.

Comment: Because you are not submitting a form anywhere.  A form is used for data submission and further processing in this case you don't need to use a form...in fact you could get rid of the <form></form> tags and it would still work.  Can you mark this as correct and upvote thanks!

Comment: I don't get it... The onclick="go()" executes before the form submit right? So how is it influenced by the button being of type submit?

Comment: The form is submitting to itself since there was no action specification.  If you take his code and place it in an html file on your desktop then run in browser you will see when you click submit it defaults to get() method and submits form to itself with parameters in the url.

Comment: I've to share Stijn's opinion. How a long gone `form` could submit anything? I mean `window.loaction.replace()` should unload the current page immediately, it's not going to wait for the end of the script execution, as `submit` will.

Comment: Debug it and see what's happening.

Comment: onclick method probably executed after onsubmit method.

Comment: But it is not (and shouldn't), just tested it locally (removed `onunload` from `body`), and you are right when saying it submits. But how ...?

Comment: I'm not sure did you try debugging to see what is happening?

Comment: I've put loggings and even alerts to `go()`, the results can be seen. I also checked the network traffic, the submit seems to be the only request there. Btw. did you noticed OP's comment where they state: "... if I type something else ... it works just fine." A page in an iframe?

Comment: Ya I'm not exactly sure what he is talking about?

Comment: Is what I'm saying... Your solution works but I don't understand it (and I hate that ;)