# Why submitting a form overrides setting location.href in a submit button click handler?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, submit

This question is inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26430575/1169519).

In a nutshell: Why `window.location.href` is not redirecting to a new page (example.com) when executing the code below?

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
    });
</script>
```

I've always believed, that setting `window.location.href` immediately loads a new page, but in this case it doesn't. Submitting the form just reloads the page instead, and setting a new location seems to be totally ignored. Why? How? What I'm missing here?

Please notice, that I'm aware of several ways how to prevent form submitting in this case, rather I'd like to know, why setting `location.href` is ignored, what is the mechanism behind the behavior? I've tried to search explanation from [the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#form-submission-algorithm), but haven't found anything so far.

**Additional information**

This seems to happen in all major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE11, Edge ...), but not when the code is run in a Stack snippet (because it's sandboxed, and won't send forms anyway). A `console.log` put in the function shows, that the click handler is executed before the actual submission is executed.

A [jsFiddle reproducing](http://jsfiddle.net/ozm5587m/) the issue.

Comment: This was a tricky one! In the end, I think it has to do with stopping the propagation of the form by returning false. Your code could probably even be refactored to do this, mixed with the answer I provided below.

Comment: i don't think he's asking how to fix it... he wants to know why it happens. Is it simply that when the form submits, it cancels the location.href change and instead submits the form?

Comment: @KevinB Yes, that's exactly what happens, `location.href` is cancelled, and the form is submitted instead. Considering `location.href` should load a new page where ever it is met, this feels weird action.

Comment: And you want to know why? i don't think anyone here will be able to answer that, unless it's specified in the spec. Otherwise, all you'll get is opinions.

Comment: @KevinB yep, my bad. Too quick on the draw to provide an answer. :)

Comment: @KevinB Yep, what is the mechanism, can I expect `location.href` would be cancelled in some other context? I tried to find something from the specs, but maybe my english is not good enough for proper search.

Comment: I can't find anything on it either. Since there's only one other situation where the user performs an action that can cause the location to change without code, it would be easy to test to see that that context does(or doesn't) behave in the same way. (click event on an anchor tag that changes the location)

Comment: I checked the link case. If there's `href="#"`, `location.href` loads a new page. If the `href` has a http address, `location.href` is ignored.

Comment: Which makes sense, because `href="#"` doesn't result in a trip to the server, therefore it happens, and then the relocation continues..

Answer (score 2):

You can see easier here what is happening step by step if you will try tu change location drunning form submission

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ozm5587m/7/)

If you will check your browser network tab than you can see that the submit request is cancelled (but still sent) by redirect request. I believe that same situation occurs when you trying to do it `onclick` or `onsubmit`  the first request just cancelling the next one and prevent `window.location.href` redirection.

[image]

Comment: Well, I've checked the Network traffic (of my code). In IE11 and Chrome it just showed the fiddle reload, no sign of `location` change. In FF `location` starts to change, but then submitting overrides it, and `location` request is left runnig behind (the Timeline shows "Browser busy").

Answer (score 1):

I belive the key thing here is not to view the problem as 'form submission vs page redirect', but as an event-listeners issue.

What you are doing is to attach an event listener to an html element. And it seems that the policy of DOM elements is to execute all the event listeners first, and then the event itself .  In your case, the page is redirected to the url you provided, because you set window.location inside the listener, then the submit event itself takes place, so the same blank page is reloaded

The fact that  "event flow process will complete after all listeners have been triggered" is stated here: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html

So far I haven't figgured out a way to execute the listeners after the event , but if that can be done, that is all you need to make this example work

Comment: The point is, that the page _is not redirected_. If it was, an event on an unloaded page couldn't submit anything. This has to have something to do with the environment, since redirecting works in the Stack snippet in [the post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26430575/1169519), which originally inspired me to ask the question.

Answer (score -1):

The main issue is that there is nothing preventing the submit button from actually submitting the form. You would need a `return false` somewhere for that to happen. I'm not fully certain whether the Submit button logic or the click handler is happening first, but regardless, the form post is taking precedence.

I was able to get the following to work:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect() {
        window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
        return false;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="GET" action="">
    <input type="submit" id="submitbtn" value="Submit" onclick="return redirect()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This example does remove the programmatic addition of the click event, but if that's a hard requirement it should be possible to add that back in.

Comment: Actually I've no requirements to use this at all. As I've said, I know how to prevent this, but I'm just curious, why `window.location.href` is ignored. The firing order is documented and clear, first click, then submit. Btw. not my downvote.

Comment: @Teemu, no worries, I was apparently a bit hasty to post an answer and glanced over the fact that you're not looking for the answer I provided! :) My best guess is that regardless of the order, both events are being permitted to fire but the form submit is taking precedence. A shot in the dark, I suppose.