# Form input:Image onClick event doesn't redirect page. HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit

I'm having issues trying to put a simple password protect script in my HTML (I know its not secure, I don't need high level protection) but the redirect function doesn't work.

I'm having trouble with the input:image Onclick action it doesn't redirect to the proper page when the correct password is entered. If I use a input:button then it works but I want to use a input:image. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Here is the Javascript:

```js
<script language="javascript">
<!--//
/*PW Script*/
function pasuser(form) {
if (form.pass.value=="fred") {              
window.location="portfolio.html";
} 
else { 
 alert("Please enter the correct Password. Or request one under contacts");
}
}

//-->
</script>
```

Here is my form to call the Javascript:

```html
 <form name="login">
            <fieldset> 
            <div class="LC_field2">
            
                <span class="ghosttext">
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"> 
              </span>
            </div>    
   <div class="LC_field3">    
                <input type="image" border="0" src="images/go_button.png" width="52" height="25" alt="Go" onClick="pasuser(this.form);" />
             </fieldset>
   </form>
```

Comment: Notice, that clicking on `input type="image"` submits the form. For some reason form submitting overrides setting the `location`. ([Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26433188/why-submitting-a-form-overrides-setting-location-href-in-a-submit-button-click-h).) Also you shouldn't hardcode passwords to the page.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to remove the useless form.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks for your suggestion. I know its not secure but the page it goes to doesn't have anything valuable. I just need a light secure layer feature

Answer (score 2):

You just have to return false on your onclick event to prevent the default browser behavior for input elements.

```
onClick="pasuser(document.forms.login); return false;"
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should do like this.

And then,

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--//
/*PW Script*/
function pasuser(form) {
    var pass = document.getElementsByName("pass")[0].value;
   if (pass == "fred") {              
    var your_url            = "portfolio.html";
    window.location.href       = your_url;
   } 
  else
  { 
    alert("Please enter the correct Password. Or request one under contacts");
  }
}

//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<input type="image" border="0" src="images/go_button.png" width="52" height="25" alt="Go" onClick="pasuser(this.form);" />
```

to this:

```
<img border="0" src="images/go_button.png" width="52" height="25" alt="Go" onClick="pasuser(document.forms.login);" />
```

Comment: No really, an `<img/>` tag with a click event is not an input field and will not trigger form submission.