# Execute javascript before submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I know the title sound similar with some other threads but it's a little bit different.I have few buttons like those:

```
<input type=button name=Ok onclick='window.location="www.bla.com/bla.php"'>
```

When the user press any of them,i want a javascript or jquery code to run, but after,i want to be send to www.bla.com/bla.php.

I have a jquery code for submitting the form:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $(':button').click(function(){
    document.getElementById('contact').submit();    
    });
```

The jquery code works,but the buttons does not...

Comment: @Teemu sorry,i forgot about window.location

Comment: You mixed up the " and ' in your Html.

Comment: @Fuzzyma How is that? Both are valid in JS and HTML.

Comment: yes but it's recommended to stay with the standard which is " in Html

Comment: @PetruLebada I guess you've [this same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26433188/1169519), submitting a form will prevent setting new `window.location` to work.

Comment: @Fuzzyma i have to mix single quotes with double quotes or the coode won't work

Comment: onclick="Javascript with ' quotes"

Comment: why are you using `name=Ok` on the button?  do you want to see that in the form submission?

Comment: @Fuzzyma It really doesn't matter, as long as the quotes are nested correctly.

Comment: @PetruLebada Have you tried an `a` tag with a clickhandler instead of a button?

Comment: @Teemu , no because i need to catch the url on the other page,(also the form methd has to be post) , so i have to use window.location to change the url as i need

Comment: @PetruLebada Actually [a link seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/gLh7qyq1/), I'm not sure if the form is submitted though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is jQuery based.

The syntax here is incorrect:

```
<input type=button name=Ok onclick="www.bla.com/bla.php">
```

Modify it as:

```
<input type=button name=Ok data-href="www.bla.com/bla.php">
```

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(':button').click(function(){
  var hrefCurr = $(this).attr('data-href');
  document.getElementById('contact').submit();
  window.location.href = hrefCurr;
});
```

Comment: sorry i forgot about window.location .. check my question again please

Comment: This is dynamic done. Please read it carefully, it should work.

Comment: if `form.submit` succeeds your javascript will stop running, do you exepct form.submit to fail?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<input class="btn" type=button name=Ok data-href="location">

$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('.btn').click(function(){

    // as you have used jQuery selector you can use it here like this 
    $('#contact').submit();   

    var location = $(this).attr("data-href");

    window.location.href  =  location;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: your answer might work,but i need it to be more particular,because i have a lot of buttons and each of them send you to different pages

Comment: you can specify location in data-href for each button at time of clicking button it will take url of that button and redirect to that url

Comment: you can specify location in the action attribute of the button.

Answer (score 2):

No javascript will execute after the form is submitted.  form submission changes window.location and that stops the javascritpt from the old window.location from executing.

but you can fake it.

- use jquery forms to submit the form (if CORS will allow that)
- or have the script at the form destination do a redirect to your desired location.
- or submit to the desired location and have the script there send the form data to where it should go

Comment: To be exact, you can execute some JS, since there's a delay before a new page is loaded, but the change of the `location.href` is blocked immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could do the job?

```
<input type='button' name='ok_btn' id='ok_btn' value='Ok'  data-href="www.bla.com/bla.php" />

$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('#ok_btn).on('click',function(){
            // Do your stuff
            // Finally:
            window.location.replace($(this).attr('data-href'));
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: This will work, since the form is not submitted in the snippet. It's not what OP wants though.

Comment: Hm, so replace `window.location...` by `$('#contact').attr('action',$(this).attr('data-href')); $('#contact').submit();` could do it ?