# window.location.href not being assigned / redirected

Tags: javascript, href, window.location

This is a followup to a prior question that you guys answered a few weeks ago.  There is HTML in a WordPress.org app which I cannot change.  A section in this HTML contains text that is hyperlinked to someURL.  I want the URL to redirect to my referrer page in order to return to whatever page I cam from when I click on this link.  The problem is that something is blocking the assignment of my referrer URL string to HREF.  I stepped through this function a hundred times in the Chrome debugger, and tried various thing (see below).  HREF simply will not change, not matter what.  Any idea why?  here is the code, and thank you for any any help on this:

```
window.onload = function () {


    document.querySelector(".button.wc-backward").onclick = function() {

        var URLstring = document.referrer;  // works fine

        window.location.href = URLstring;  // ref unchanged

        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = URLstring; },100);  // same result

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What element is `.button.wc-backward`? `A`? If so, you've to prevent the default action of the link, otherwise the pending server call blocks the changes to the `location` object's properties.

Comment: the element is this '<a class="button wc-backward" href="https://needlepoint.land/index.php/catalog-2/">Return To Shop</a>'  i thought 'return false;' blocked default behavior.

Comment: you mention that your previous question has been answered, remember to check the correct answer. As for the current question, Amina's demo works great.

Comment: Could be something else is overwriting the `onclick` property after you set it. You should really use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: not sure where to mark the correct answer but will look closely for that.

Comment: there is an alternative version of this for a page with another "return to" box that i wanted to redirect.  same problem:  that code looked like this 'window.onload = function() {
     
        var myClass = document.getElementsByClassName('return-to-shop'); 
   
        myClass[0].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location.href = document.referrer;
            });
        }
        '

Comment: You could use an element which doesn't cause a trip to the server, for example `button type="button"`, or `a` with `href="#"`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with you jscode, I have added it to here:
[Example on github](http://aminag.github.io/goref.html?c)

And it is working. (You will be redirected back to stackoverflow).

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
 window.onload = function () {
    document.querySelector(".button.wc-backward").onclick = function() {
        var URLstring = document.referrer;  // works fine
        window.location.href = URLstring;  // ref unchanged
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = URLstring; 
        }, 100);  // same result
        return false;  
    }
}
</script>
<a href="www.google.com" class="button wc-backward">the link</a>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you.  then it baffles me why it is not working with the theme I am using on WP for an ecommerce app.  Thank you again!

Comment: Give us a link. or download the HTML (as webpage complere in the save dialog box of your browsers) and add a link to it.

Comment: also when i evaluate href on the console using chrome it remains unchanged :-(

Comment: here is the link [https://needlepoint.land/index.php/cart/] just go to this page from the HP and click on the box.  you will always be taken to the catalog no matter what.

Comment: I suppose this has something to do with the sandbox model. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26430575/1169519) OP had a similar problem, but funnily their code works fine in the sandboxed Stack Snippet. I posted a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26433188/1169519) about the `href` issue, but all good answers were given by Kevin B in the comments.

Comment: not sure how the sandbox model applies as i am not going cross domain, but then i am no expert.

Comment: i can only leave this web site open a few more minutes as this is still in dev mode.

Comment: @cataloupe You're not, but github, that's why Amina's example page might work. If you'd try to create a proper example of your problem at http://jsfiddle.net , you can't even save a newly-created snippet ...

Comment: hmmm i really appreciated all the help but all the examples i have read (for the last 3-4 hours + reading MDN documentation indicate this should work.)  Why simple JS variable assignment is not being honored (or is being blocked), when I am writing the code under my own admin ID is beyond me.

Comment: i am shutting down the site now.  thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You code is wokring... do you like to try this one too

```
window.location.assign(URLstring)
```